# Program doesn't read memory well

Tags: programming

My program does not read the contents of the memory card, in this case the file "objects.txt". What I wanted to do was: the program reads the objects contained in the text file and allocates the table, then organizes the table alphabetically.

Something is escaping me. Another thing, how do I put a function recognizing if the user pressed a button and if pressed, the program continues?

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// define some values used by the panel and buttons
int lcd_key     = 0;
int adc_key_in  = 0;
int x = 0;
String files, memo, memo1;
int sizef = 0;
int sizef1 = 0;
int sizef2 = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;

struct objeto_celeste_s {
  char nome[20];
  float ar;
  float dec;
};
typedef struct objeto_celeste_s objeto_celeste;

char * tab1 [6];
int myCompareFunction (const void * arg1, const void * arg2) {
  return strcmp (*(char **) arg1, *(char **) arg2);
}

File root;
File file;

#define btnRIGHT  0
#define btnUP     1
#define btnDOWN   2
#define btnLEFT   3
#define btnSELECT 4
#define btnNONE   5

char * list[] = {"1.Modo Normal    ", "2.Modo Teste    ", "3.Modo GoTo     ", "4.Modo Manual  "};

// read the buttons
int read_LCD_buttons() {
  adc_key_in = analogRead(0);
  if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE;
  if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT;
  if (adc_key_in < 250)  return btnUP;
  if (adc_key_in < 400)  return btnDOWN;
  if (adc_key_in < 450)  return btnLEFT;
  if (adc_key_in < 650)  return btnSELECT;
  return btnNONE; // when all others fail, return this...
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println ("Welcome!");
  Serial.println ("Selecione um modo no lcd.");
  lcd.begin (16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor (0, 0);
  lcd.print ("  Selecione um");
  lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
  lcd.print ("      modo    ");
  delay (1000);
  lcd.clear ();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(">");
  lcd.println(list[0]);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print (" ");
  lcd.println(list[1]);
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();  // read the buttons
  switch (lcd_key) {
    // depending on which button was pushed, we perform an action
    case btnRIGHT:
      break;
    case btnLEFT:
      break;
    case btnUP:
      if (x == 1) {
        x--;
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[0]);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print (" ");
        lcd.println(list[1]);
      }
      break;
      if (x == 3) {
        x--;
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[2]);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print (" ");
        lcd.println(list[3]);
      }
      break;
    case btnDOWN:
      if (x == 0) {
        x++;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[1]);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.println("                ");
      }
      break;
      if (x == 2) {
        x++;
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[3]);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.println("                ");
      }
      break;
    case btnSELECT:
      if (x == 0) {
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.print ("Modo Normal");
        Serial.println ("Selecionou o modo normal!");
        delay (1000);
        if (SD.exists("objectos.txt")) {
          Serial.println("O ficheiro 'objetos' foi encontrado!");
          lcd.clear ();
          lcd.setCursor (0, 0);
          lcd.print ("Modo Normal");
          delay (1000);
          file = SD.open("objectos.txt", FILE_READ);
          if (file) {
            while (file.available()) {
              String line = file.readStringUntil('\n');
              sizef++;
            }
          } else {
            //se houver erro a abrir o ficheiro
            Serial.println("Erro a abrir o ficheiro 'objectos.txt'.");
          }
          objeto_celeste *tab = (objeto_celeste *)malloc((sizef) * sizeof(objeto_celeste));
          Serial.print ("Contados ");
          Serial.print (sizef);
          Serial.println (" objetos no ficheiro objectos.txt.");
          if (tab == NULL) {
            lcd.clear ();
            lcd.print ("Erro a alocar memoria");
            Serial.println ("Erro a alocar memória");
            while (1) { };
          } else {
            Serial.print ("Memória alocada para ");
            Serial.print (sizef);
            Serial.println (" objectos.");
            lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
            lcd.print ("Alocados ");
            lcd.print (sizef);
            lcd.print (" obj");
          }
          file.close();
          char * line1 = (char*) malloc(15);
          file = SD.open("objectos.txt", FILE_READ);
          if (file) {
            Serial.println ("Carregando informação para a memória:");
            while (file.available()) {
              if (file.read() == '\n') {
                char * justafun = strtok (line1, " "); //divide em tokens
                while (justafun != NULL) {
                  if (y == 0) {
                    strcpy (tab[sizef2].nome, justafun);
                    Serial.print ("[");
                    Serial.print (sizef2);
                    Serial.print ("] ");
                    Serial.print(tab[sizef2].nome);
                    Serial.print (" ");
                    y++;
                  }
                  if (y == 1) {
                    tab[sizef2].ar = atof (justafun);
                    Serial.print (tab[sizef2].ar);
                    Serial.print (" ");
                    y++;
                  }
                  if (y == 2) {
                    tab[sizef2].dec = atof (justafun);
                    Serial.println (tab[sizef2].dec);
                    sizef2++;
                    y = 0;
                  }
                  justafun = strtok (NULL, " ");
                }
              }
            }
          }
          file.close ();
          delay (1500);
          lcd.clear ();
          Serial.println ("Proceda ao alinhamento manual do telescópio.");
          lcd.setCursor (0, 0);
          lcd.print ("Proceda ao ");
          lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
          lcd.print ("Alinhamento man.");
          Serial.println ("Depois de o alinhamento estar concluido, pressione o botão Select para prosseguir o programa.");
          //colocar aqui função para reconhecer quando pressiona select
          if (Serial1.available()) {
            int inByte = "V"; //Se o alinhamento está concluido, 0 para não e 1 para sim
            Serial1.write (inByte);
          }
          while (!Serial1) {
            if (Serial1.available()) {
              int inByte = "V";
              Serial1.write (inByte);
              int inByte1 = "e";
              Serial1.write (inByte1);
            }
          }
          delay (1000);
          Serial.println ("Tabela ordenada alfabeticamente:");
          qsort (tab->nome, sizef, sizeof (char *), myCompareFunction);
          for (int i = 0; i < sizef; i++)
            Serial.println (tab[i].nome);
          delay (1000);
          lcd.clear ();
          lcd.print ("Carregue Select");
          lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
          lcd.print ("Para modo manual");
          Serial.println ("Carregue em Select para ir para o modo manual e assim continuar com o programa.");
        } else {
          Serial.println ("O ficheiro 'objetos' não existe.");
          lcd.clear ();
          lcd.print ("Erro nao encontrado");
          delay (2000);
          while (1) { };
        }
      }
      if (x == 1) {
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.print ("Modo Teste");
        Serial.println ("Selecionou o modo teste!");
        delay (2000);
        if (SD.exists("teste.txt")) {
          Serial.println("O ficheiro 'teste.txt' foi encontrado!");
          lcd.clear ();
          lcd.setCursor (0, 0);
          lcd.print ("Modo Teste");
          lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
          lcd.print ("Ficheiro encontrado");
          delay (2000);
          file = SD.open("teste.txt", FILE_READ);
          if (file) {
            while (file.available()) {//ler o ficheiro
              String line = file.readStringUntil('\n');
              sizef++;
            }
            files = "Contados " + String (sizef) + " objetos no ficheiro teste.txt.";
            Serial.println (files);
            objeto_celeste *tab = (objeto_celeste *)malloc((sizef) * sizeof(objeto_celeste));
            memo = "Alocados " + String (sizef) + " obj  ";
            memo1 = "Memória alocada para " + String (sizef) + " objetos.";
            if (tab == NULL) {
              lcd.clear ();
              lcd.print ("Erro alocar memoria");
              Serial.println ("Erro a alocar memória");
              while (1) { };
            } else {
              Serial.println (memo1);
              lcd.setCursor (0, 1);
              lcd.print (memo);
            }
            file.close();
          } else {
            //se houver erro a abrir o ficheiro
            Serial.println("Erro a abrir o ficheiro 'teste.txt'.");
          }
        } else {
          Serial.println ("O ficheiro 'teste.txt' não foi encontrado.");
          lcd.clear ();
          lcd.print ("Erro nao encontrado");
          delay (2000);
          while (1) { };
        }
      }
      break;
    case btnNONE:
      break;
  }
  delay (200);
}
```

Comment: You are never using anything of the content oft objects.txt. in the first read you only count the lines in the file and in the second read loop you only do something, when a newline is read, nothing else

Comment: Thank you, so in the second read i should do what?

Comment: How about actually reading the lines you counted previously and then extracting the data you need from them.

Comment: How i do that? :/

Comment: Read bytes into a buffer with the `read()` function and then use the data. Since you havent described what kind of data you have in the file, we cannot help you doing this

Comment: How come that you have this big program with two loops for reading from a file but don't know how to read a file? Is this really your code?

Comment: Yes, it's my code. My data is "name  ar coordenates dec coordenates" ex: Alnitak 05h40m45.5s -01°56'34"

Comment: My english is not good enough, chrisl. But yes, i know how to read a file, ofc!

Comment: In first loop i want to know how many lines of text i have, so i do a loop and a container o increase loop for loop, in second loop i want to divide date lines in tokens and save that token in the respective tab.

Comment: @1manonearth, your code is very poorly indented. ... most of it is just a blob of text ... it is difficult to follow the program flow because of the way it is. ... it requires reformatting before it can be looked at .... most people do not have the time to format your code so that it can be debugged .... you may get a good answer if you spend some time and clean up your code

Comment: here is an example of properly formatted code ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51944/sending-data-from-webserver-to-arduino

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can't add a button that restarts/continues the program. Because of all the `delay(...)` in your code. The arduino chip cant read your input and your button, while it is in a delay mode and hence no reading from the button. Read more about [**non-blocking delay**](https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2017/09/arduino-tutorial-using-millis-instead-of-delay/)

You need to keep the main `loop` method ongoing so the microcontroller-cpu can do it's work. Instead of waiting in a `delay` loop, doing nothing.

So don't use any `delay`, they are good for beginner to jump start into Arduino.

[image: No delay]