# don't save on tab

Tags: debugging

Ok, I made some changes to the code and I wish they would see it.

At the moment the program has a bug, it is not saving the contents of the txt file to the table, can someone give some lights?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// define some values used by the panel and buttons
int lcd_key     = 0;
int adc_key_in  = 0;
int x = 1;
String files, memo, memo1;
int sizef = 0;
int sizef1 = 0;
int sizef2 = 0;
int y=0;
int z=1;
int d=0;
int u=0;
int r=0;
int l=0;
int indice_objetos=0;

struct objeto_celeste_s {
  char nome[20];
  float ar;
  float dec; 
  };
typedef struct objeto_celeste_s objeto_celeste; 

void rightfunction (int rate){
 char cmd[] = {'P',2,16,36,rate,0,0,0};

  for(int i=0; i<(int)(sizeof(cmd)/sizeof(char)); i++)
    Serial1.print(cmd[i]);

}

void leftfunction (int rate){
 char cmd[] = {'P',2,16,37,rate,0,0,0};

  for(int i=0; i<(int)(sizeof(cmd)/sizeof(char)); i++)
    Serial1.print(cmd[i]);

}

void upfunction (int rate){
 char cmd[] = {'P',2,17,36,rate,0,0,0};

  for(int i=0; i<(int)(sizeof(cmd)/sizeof(char)); i++)
    Serial1.print(cmd[i]);
}

void downfunction (int rate){
 char cmd[] = {'P',2,17,37,rate,0,0,0};

  for(int i=0; i<(int)(sizeof(cmd)/sizeof(char)); i++)
    Serial1.print(cmd[i]);
}

File file;

#define btnRIGHT  0
#define btnUP     1
#define btnDOWN   2
#define btnLEFT   3
#define btnSELECT 4
#define btnNONE   5

char * list[]={"1.Modo Normal    ","2.Modo Teste    "};

// read the buttons
int read_LCD_buttons()
{

adc_key_in = analogRead(0);
if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE;
if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT;  
if (adc_key_in < 250)  return btnUP; 
if (adc_key_in < 400)  return btnDOWN; 
if (adc_key_in < 450)  return btnLEFT;
if (adc_key_in < 650)  return btnSELECT;   

return btnNONE;  // when all others fail, return this...
}

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial1.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
 } 
 Serial.println ("Welcome!");
 Serial.println ("Efectue o alinhamento do telescópio, depois carregue no botão UP.");
 lcd.begin (16,2);
 lcd.setCursor (0,0);
 lcd.print ("Efectue alinham.");
 lcd.setCursor (0,1);
 lcd.print ("E carregue UP");
 delay (1000);

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}


void loop() {

lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();  // read the buttons

 switch (lcd_key)  // depending on which button was pushed, we perform an action
 {
   case btnRIGHT:   
     if (z==0){
      rightfunction (9);
      Serial.println ("Andar para a direita a uma velocidade de 9.");
      z=1;
      r=1;
      break;
     }

     if (r==1){
      rightfunction (0);
      Serial.println ("Parar de andar para a direita.");
      z=0;
      r==0;
      break;
     }

   case btnLEFT:
     if (z==0){
      leftfunction (9);
      Serial.println ("Andar para a esquerda a uma velocidade de 9");
      z=1;
      l=1;
      break;
     }

     if (l==1){
      leftfunction (0);
      Serial.println ("Parar de andar para a esquerda.");
      z=0;
      l=0;
      break;
     }

   case btnUP:
      if (z==0){
       upfunction (9);
       Serial.println ("Andar para cima a uma velocidade de 9");
       z=1;
       u=1;
       break;
     }

      if (u==1){
       upfunction (0);
       Serial.println ("Parar de andar para cima.");
       z=0;
       u=0;
       break;
     }


      if(x==1){
        x--;
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[0]);
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print (" ");
        lcd.println(list[1]);
        break;
      }
   case btnDOWN:
      if (z==0){
       downfunction (9);
       Serial.println ("Andar para baixo a uma velocidade de 9.");
       z=1;
       d=1;
       break;
      }

      if (d==1){
       downfunction (0);
       Serial.println ("Parar de andar para baixo.");
       z=0;
       d=0;
       break;
      }


      if(x==0){
        x++;
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print(">");
        lcd.println(list[1]);
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.println("                ");
        break;
      }

   case btnSELECT:
    if (x==2){
      Serial.println ("Bem-vindo ao Modo Manual.");
      lcd.clear ();
      lcd.print ("Modo Manual");
      lcd.setCursor (0,1);
      lcd.print ("Reset p/mod GoTo");
      Serial.println ("Pressione os botões UP, DOWN, RIGHT ou LEFT no arduíno para controlar o telescópio.");
      z=0;
      break;
    }


    if (x==0){
    lcd.clear ();  
    lcd.print ("Modo Normal");
    Serial.println ("Selecionou o modo normal!");
    delay (1000);
    if (SD.exists("objectos.txt")) {
    Serial.println("O ficheiro 'objetos' foi encontrado!");
    lcd.clear ();
    lcd.setCursor (0,0);
    lcd.print ("Modo Normal");
    delay (1000);

    file = SD.open("objectos.txt", FILE_READ);
    if (file) {
    while (file.available()) {
     String line = file.readStringUntil('\n');
     sizef++;
    }
    } else {//se houver erro a abrir o ficheiro 
     Serial.println("Erro a abrir o ficheiro 'objectos.txt'.");
    }
     Serial.print ("Contados ");
     Serial.print (sizef);
     Serial.println (" objetos no ficheiro objectos.txt.");

     objeto_celeste *tab =(objeto_celeste *)malloc((sizef) * sizeof(objeto_celeste));

     if (tab==NULL){
      lcd.clear ();
      lcd.print ("Erro a alocar memoria");
      Serial.println ("Erro a alocar memória");
      while (1){ }; 

     }else{

      Serial.print ("Memória alocada para ");
      Serial.print (sizef);
      Serial.println (" objectos.");
      lcd.setCursor (0,1);
      lcd.print ("Alocados ");
      lcd.print (sizef);
      lcd.print (" obj");
      }

      file.close(); 


    char * line1 =(char*) malloc(sizeof(String)); 

    file = SD.open("objectos.txt", FILE_READ); 

    if (file) {
     Serial.println ("Carregando informação para a memória:");

     while (file.available()) {

     char c = file.read ();

     if (c=='\n'){ 

     char * justafun = strtok (line1," "); //divide em tokens 

     while (justafun !=NULL){

      switch (indice_objetos) {
          case 1:
            tab[sizef2].ar = atof(justafun); //to float


            indice_objetos++;
            break;
          case 2:
            tab[sizef2].dec = atof(justafun);

            sizef2++;
            indice_objetos=0;
            break;
          case 0:
            strcpy(tab[sizef2].nome, justafun); //this one is a string
            indice_objetos++;
            break; 
      }
      justafun = strtok (NULL, " ");  
      }

      if (line1==NULL){
      Serial.print ("Falhou na linha ");
      Serial.println (sizef2);

     }else{
       line1="";
    }  
   }else{
     sprintf(line1, "%s%c", line1, char(c));
     }
    }
   }
  file.close (); 

  delay (1500); 

  if (Serial1.available()) {
   int inByte = 'V';
   Serial1.write (inByte);
   int inByte1 = 'e';
   Serial1.write (inByte1);
  }

delay (1000);

Serial.println ("Tabela ordenada alfabeticamente:");

 x=2;
 delay (1000);
 lcd.clear ();
 Serial.println ("Modo GoTo. Para entrar em Modo Manual pressione o botão select.");
 lcd.print ("Modo GoTo");
 lcd.setCursor (0,1);
 lcd.print ("Slct p/Modo Man.");


 }else {

    Serial.println ("O ficheiro 'objetos' não existe.");
    lcd.clear ();
    lcd.print ("Erro nao encontrado");
    delay (2000);
    while(1) { };
  }
 } 

    if (x==1){
      lcd.clear ();
      lcd.print ("Modo Teste");
      Serial.println ("Selecionou o modo teste!");
      delay (2000);

      if (SD.exists("teste.txt")) {
      Serial.println("O ficheiro 'teste.txt' foi encontrado!");
      lcd.clear ();
      lcd.setCursor (0,0);
      lcd.print ("Modo Teste");
      lcd.setCursor (0,1);
      lcd.print ("Ficheiro encontrado");
      delay (2000);

      file = SD.open("teste.txt", FILE_READ);

      if (file) {
      while (file.available()) {//ler o ficheiro
      String line = file.readStringUntil('\n');
      sizef++;
     }

      files = "Contados " + String (sizef) + " objetos no ficheiro teste.txt.";
      Serial.println (files);
      objeto_celeste *tab = (objeto_celeste *)malloc((sizef) * sizeof(objeto_celeste));
      memo = "Alocados " + String (sizef) + " obj  ";
      memo1= "Memória alocada para " + String (sizef) + " objetos.";

      if (tab==NULL){
        lcd.clear ();
        lcd.print ("Erro alocar memoria");
        Serial.println ("Erro a alocar memória");
        while (1){ };

      }else{

        Serial.println (memo1);
        lcd.setCursor (0,1);
        lcd.print (memo);
      }

      file.close();

     } else {//se houver erro a abrir o ficheiro 
      Serial.println("Erro a abrir o ficheiro 'teste.txt'.");
     }

    }else {
      Serial.println ("O ficheiro 'teste.txt' não foi encontrado.");
      lcd.clear ();
      lcd.print ("Erro nao encontrado");
      delay (2000);
      while(1) { };
    }
   }
     break;

   case btnNONE:
      break;
 }    
 delay (200);
}
```

This is the content of txt.

P.S. I know the "Ar" section is wrong, it's just for test purposes.

```
Syrius 6.45 -16.42 
Deneb 20.41 +45.16 
Capella 5.16 +45.59 
Rigel 5.14 -8.12 
Vega 18.36 +38.47 
Alnitak 05.40 -01.56
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51957/program-dont-read-memory-well

Comment: Hi, this is too long for a comment in other post.

Comment: And the code is not the same...

Comment: Why do you except the contents of your textfile to be saved into the array `tab`? You read one character at a time but aren't doing anything else with it than using it in an if-statement. You have to actually put your information into your data array

Comment: Consider that you always can edit your question. Code or other long things should not be placed in code, but the question should be edited. For me it seems, that you have the same problem as last time. If not, please be more specific

Comment: else{sprintf(line1, "%s%c", line1, char(c));

Comment: You should edit the code in your question to be a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Very likely you'll discover the problem in the process of creating it, and if not, you'll create a question which might be of use to someone else in the future, which is what this site is about.

Comment: @1manonearth: This line is not in the code of your question. Edit it, so that it reflects the code you are actually using

Comment: I have edited. Can u see?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have found your problem:

Before reading the file you are allocating memory with `malloc()` and creating a pointer `line1` to it. `malloc()` takes the number of bytes to allocate as a parameter. Here you use `sizeof(String)`, which would give you the size of a new String object. But the point of the String object is, that is dynamically allocates the memory for the string of characters. So the created buffer `line1` is most likely to small for your text. You have to allocate the buffer with the maximum number of characters of all lines.

But you should consider, that using `malloc()` or any other dynamic memory allocation is dangerous on microcontrollers, which don't have much RAM. If you are doing it to often you get heap fragmentation, essentially making swiss cheese of your heap. If possible you should use a statically declared array or at least allocate memory only once during the lifecycle of your program.